# Change the number of particles in the PF dynamically

Tags: julia, particle-filter

I am trying to create a particle filter method where the number of particles is adaptive, meaning it changes dynamically depending on whether the method is converging or not. I want to take inspiration from the repository https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/ParticleFilters.jl, but I don't quite understand how it works or where the particles used by the `BasicParticleFilter` are set. I understand that it is initialized when the `BasicParticleFilter` is declared, but I don't fully understand where it is stored afterwards or when it is used. For example, what is the purpose of `_particle_memory` and `_weight_memory`? Which attribute of which method should I change for the `update` method to automatically adjust the number of particles it generates?

Comment: In case this question is closed (as being "too broad"), please try asking on the Julia Discourse forum.